# Magento 2 .Error : Cannot use a scalar value as an array

Tags: magento2

I'm using **Magento 2.2.1 CE**.I got following error when I opened admin panel

```
   "0":"Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in 
\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\Session\\SessionManager.php on line 470"
```

How to solve this ?

Comment: This above fix still works for magento 2.3.3, but the line is 508 not 482.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a Magento bug for not returning array if session has a value.

Temporary fix is, change line 482 to:

```
return isset($_SESSION[self::HOST_KEY]) ? [$_SESSION[self::HOST_KEY]] : [];
```

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to overcome the issue is to clear site data storage in your browser to refresh a session data